Select the Users and Roles from User Manager and Role Manager in Multilst to send a mail
I have created a workflow where, at each step, an email is sent to a selected user. The user should be chosen from the User Manager/Role Manager.
To achieve this, I plan to use a Multi list or Tree-list field to select both users and roles in two separate fields. How can I fetch the user and role details to implement this functionality effectively?
Your guidance is greatly appreciated!

Easiest You can achieve it through sitecore powershell, if you don't need a complex implementation.Go through below points, hope it will help.

In your both felds, give datasource as powershell script, i.e.    script: followed by the    path.[https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules/integration-points/data-sources]    [https://rinkusitecore.wordpress.com/2022/05/25/sitecore-datasource-based-on-context-site-using-powershell-script-on-non-sxa-sites/]
e.g.  script:/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script    Library/....your whole path...

for both these fields write script (there path only you need to give in datasource)

To get list of users, get-user cmdlet(https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/security/get-user)    e.g. to get all user list, Get-User -Filter *

To get Role detail
a. Get-Role cmdlet if need role detail
b. Get-RoleMember cmdlet, if need user role details. e.g.  Get-RoleMember -Identity developer , users against developer role [https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/security/get-rolemember]


This way your both field data will driven as per your requirement
